# Burninate the "modify" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

As the [modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modify)'s tag excerpt itself says:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG.

This tag has 474 questions, spanning on topics from java to asp.net with more or less anything and everything in the middle.

474 is a bit much for manually removing it from each question and having the automatic tag reaper handle it.
Can it be burninated please?

Since the tag's age came into question (in the comments), here's a bit more information:

- The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19291169/revisions) was created on October 10th, 2013, and was not edited since, as was the [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19291170/revisions).
- The [oldest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323265/c-sharp-can-i-modify-request-forms-variables) it's applied to was created on November 27th, 2008, and was not edited since.

In other words, the tag was created at least ~5 years before the tag wiki. If someone's aware of a better method to determine when it was created, please share.

Comment: Whomever put that in the tag wiki forgot to bring that up on Meta at the time. Shame on them, we would have had about 100 posts fewer to burninate.

Comment: No, the tag **wiki** was created with that description. The tag itself was created years earlier. The person creating the tag wiki should have called for a burnination instead.

Comment: Won't someone please think of the peasants??

Comment: @Inversus I didn't understand that comment. Can you explain what you mean please?

Comment: Can we go and kill it? With fire?

Comment: @hlt I think that it is time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I have removed the [modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modify) tag from all 474 questions because it added absolutely no context or useful information to any of them.

It <del>will be</del> has been [removed from the system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info), and no one will be able to add it to a question without re-creating the tag, which requires 1.5k reputation.

Comment: I voted up your answer as a "Wow" for going through and modifying all 474 questions! :)